# Universal ctags on Windows

Tags: windows-10, ctags

I'm new to ctags. After reading some information about the program, I concluded that "Universal ctags" is the newest version (successor of "exhuberant ctags") and still under active development:
https://ctags.io/

Most people use it on Linux. For some specific reasons I need to use it on Windows (Windows 10, 64-bit to be more precise). I'm looking for an executable file of Universal ctags.
Do you know where to download such an executable?

*PS: I'm not interested in the cygwin-approach (again for some specific reasons, but that would lead us too far here).*
*EDIT: For a better understanding of ctags output, please refer to this question: [Understanding the ctags file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933837/understanding-the-ctags-file-format)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found binary executables for the Windows directly on the project website under the section downloads: https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags-win32/releases

Comment: Waw, thank you so much! After all those months, finally someone answered. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can install Universal ctags on Windows directly with the help of
[chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/universal-ctags):

```
choco install universal-ctags
```

Or Install via [scoop](https://scoop.sh/):

```
scoop bucket add extras
scoop install universal-ctags
```